# Coldfusion REReplace (to parse Twitter Feed)

Tags: regex, coldfusion

I have a twitter feed in the format:

```
1. Username: Blah blah http://something.com #hashtag
2. Username: Blah blah http://something.com #hashtag
3. Username: Blah blah http://something.com #hashtag
```

I'm removed the username, but how do I wrap tags (for styling) around the http:// parts and the #hashtags?

Here is my current coldfusion code:

```
 <cfset feedurl="http://twitter.com/statuses/user_timeline/MyUserID.rss" />
    <cffeed
        source="#feedurl#"
        properties="feedmeta"
        query="feeditems" />
    <cffeed
    source="#feedurl#"
    properties="feedmeta"
    query="feeditems" />
<ul>
    <cfoutput query="feeditems">
        <cfsavecontent variable="twitterString">
        #content#
        </cfsavecontent>
        <li>#REReplace(twitterString, "UserName: ", "")#</li>
    </cfoutput>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This worked for me:

```
 <cfset feedurl="http://twitter.com/statuses/user_timeline/jakefeasel.rss" />
    <cffeed
        source="#feedurl#"
        properties="feedmeta"
        query="feeditems" />
    <cffeed
    source="#feedurl#"
    properties="feedmeta"
    query="feeditems" />
<ul>
    <cfoutput query="feeditems">

        <cfsavecontent variable="twitterString">
        #REReplace(content, "UserName: ", "")#
        </cfsavecontent>
        <cfset formattedString = twitterString>

        <cfloop array='#[{"regex" = 'http://\S+', "class" = "URL"}, {"regex" = "##\w+", "class" = "hashTag"}]#' index="regexStruct">
            <cfset currentPos = 0>
            <cfset matches = ReFindNoCase(regexStruct.regex, twitterString, currentPos, true)>
            <cfloop condition="matches.len[1] IS NOT 0">
                <cfset formattedString = Replace(formattedString, mid(twitterString, matches.pos[1], matches.len[1]), "<span class='#regexStruct.class#'>" & mid(twitterString, matches.pos[1], matches.len[1]) & "</span>")>

                <cfset currentPos = matches.pos[1] + matches.len[1]>
                <cfset matches = ReFindNoCase(regexStruct.regex, twitterString, currentPos, true)>
            </cfloop>
        </cfloop>

        <li>
            #formattedString#
        </li>
    </cfoutput>
</ul>
```

You'll obviously have to provide styles for the "URL" and "hashtag" classes.